# How to crop with ellipsis formatted multiline text inside of ahidden block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, overflow

I have:

- jQuery
- [jQuery dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) plugin to crop with ellipsis formatted text according the container size.
- [jQuery Actual](https://github.com/dreamerslab/jquery.actual) plugin to get the size of hidden elements.

These plugins work. The problem appears when I need to crop the text inside of the hidden container. In this case cropping is either ignored or fails with exception because of setting the content of br tag.

How can I crop the text inside of hidden container?

http://jsfiddle.net/Lhs513ws/1/

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $($(this).data("dest")).find("div").dotdotdot().end().show();
  });
});
```

```css
section {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 256px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
  margin: 8px;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4hAcxkH4"></script> <!-- dotdotdot -->
<script src="//pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KpmR9HmG"></script> <!-- actual -->

<p>
  <button data-dest="#visible">На видимой</button>
  <button data-dest="#hidden">На скрытой</button>
</p>

<section id="visible">
  <div><strong>CyberLink PowerDirector 12</strong> выводит процесс создания видео на абсолютно новый уровень. Функция <em>MultiCam</em> поддерживает до 4 камер, что позволяет пользователю работать с записями, произведенными несколькими устройствами одновременно. Программа включает в себя модуль Theme Designer, который позволяет создавать безупречные анимационные 3D слайд-шоу из видео и фотографий.</div>
</section>

<section id="hidden">
  <div><strong>CyberLink PowerDirector 12</strong> выводит процесс создания видео на абсолютно новый уровень. Функция <em>MultiCam</em> поддерживает до 4 камер, что позволяет пользователю работать с записями, произведенными несколькими устройствами одновременно. Программа включает в себя модуль Theme Designer, который позволяет создавать безупречные анимационные 3D слайд-шоу из видео и фотографий.</div>
</section>
```

PS: [Same question in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/445167/178988).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, I've found the solution. Tomorrow try it in a real code, but it seems to be ok.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lhs513ws/7/

```js
$(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        var $container = $($(this).data("dest")), $dest = $container.find(".dest");
        
        if ($dest.is(":visible")) {
            $dest.dotdotdot();
        } else {
            var $marker = $("<div>");
            
            var width = $dest.actual('width'), height = $dest.actual('height');
            
            var $temp = $("<div>").css({
                position: 'fixed',
                left: '-99999px'
            }).appendTo("body");
            
            $marker.replaceWith(
             $dest
                 .before($marker)
                 .width(width).height(height)
                 .detach().appendTo($temp).dotdotdot()
                 .detach()
                 .width("").height("")
            );
            
            $temp.remove();
        }
        
        $container.show();
    });
});
```

```css
section {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 256px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid;
    float: left;
    margin: 8px;
    position: relative;
}

.dest {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    border: 1px dotted red;
}

#hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4hAcxkH4"></script> <!-- dotdotdot -->
<script src="//pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KpmR9HmG"></script> <!-- actual -->

<p>
    <button data-dest="#visible">На видимой</button>
    <button data-dest="#hidden">На скрытой</button>
</p>

<section id="visible">
    <div>123</div>
    <div class="dest"><strong>CyberLink PowerDirector 12</strong> выводит процесс создания видео на абсолютно новый уровень. Функция <em>MultiCam</em> поддерживает до 4 камер, что позволяет пользователю работать с записями, произведенными несколькими устройствами одновременно. Программа включает в себя модуль Theme Designer, который позволяет создавать безупречные анимационные 3D слайд-шоу из видео и фотографий.</div>
    <div>456</div>
</section>

<section id="hidden">
    <div>123</div>
    <div class="dest"><strong>CyberLink PowerDirector 12</strong> выводит процесс создания видео на абсолютно новый уровень. Функция <em>MultiCam</em> поддерживает до 4 камер, что позволяет пользователю работать с записями, произведенными несколькими устройствами одновременно. Программа включает в себя модуль Theme Designer, который позволяет создавать безупречные анимационные 3D слайд-шоу из видео и фотографий.</div>
    <div>456</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just show it before the `dotdotdot` call, if you need to hide it again just hide it right after:

```
$($(this).data("dest")).show().dotdotdot();
```

or

```
$($(this).data("dest")).show().dotdotdot().hide();
```

Comment: No. It was just an example. In reality the block isn't displayed as soon as `dotdotdot` is called. The block is displayed asynchronously after validating server-side condition. And about show, apply and hide. Firstly, I'm afraid that this block will become visible - it will change a big part of layout. Secondly, you copied a code from jsfiddle, not from the question. The difference is that not the destination block is hidden, but one of its parents, so this solution becomes "remember which parents are not visible, show them, apply the plugin and restore parents state" - not a good way.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, it helped me to find the solution.